# Simple Hello World Zend frameworks for PHP Script Required

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework, adaptor

According to Phpinfo Zend is installed (Zend Engine v2.1.0) .
How ever when I call zend database commands they are swallowed without response or error message. (The script has been tested on my local server).

I am looking for a "Zend hello world" php script which will tell me that Zend is running OK.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're mixing up two not related things. Zend framework and Zend Engine.
What database commands are you 'calling'? What kind of Zend hello word, do you mean world, php script do you want and what should it show you?

Comment: Ah, you may have a point, I am so at the beginning of my learning curve I hadn't realised that. I've installed Zend on my own local server.

Comment: What have you installed? What do you want to do? Zend Framework is a library, Zend Engine is a compiler. What do you have problems with?

Comment: hi
I've installed zend frameworks on my local/test server no problem. i now realise that because I could see ZEND mentioned in PHPInfo on the Live Server I falsely assumed that Zend Frameworks was already installed on the Live Server.

My question is are ISP's generally willing to install Zend Frameworks or can I install it via FTP?

Comment: It's a library so it doesn't need to be 'installed'. Or if you want to use the term installation then this would just mean to up- or download (wget) the library to the required location. Be that your application/library folder or a shared php location.

Comment: ZF is just a bundle of normal PHP and HTML files, it's none of your hosting providers concern whether or not you use it on the respective hosting.